# How to access Base attributes in child class?

Tags: php, inheritance

Here is the code:

```
 <? php
class Animal
    {    
        public $type = 'Animal';    
        function printProperties ()
            {
                echo $this->type;
            }
    }

class Dog extends Animal
    {
        public $type = 'Dog';

        function printProperties()
            {
                echo $this->type.'<br>';
                parent::printProperties ();
            }

$aDog  = new Dog;
$aDog-> printProperties ();    
?>
```

Code prints `Dog newl Dog`

I expected the output to be `Dog newline Animal`. How to get this result. Can't I access base attributes in achild class if I overwrite a property?

Comment: You overwrite `$type` in the second class so `Dog<br>Dog` is expected.

Comment: So there is no way to access the base properties within the child class if I overwrite parent properties?

Comment: As explained you're over writing type, so change it to say `$this->breed` in your dog class that way `$this->type` will not lose it's value. That way you have an animal type and a breed of dog. Which makes more sense for readability anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class foo {
    var $x;
    function foofoo()
    {
        $this->x = "foofoo";
        return;
    }
}
class bar extends foo {
    // we have var $x; from the parent already here.
    function barbar()
    {
        parent::foofoo();
        echo $this->x;
    }
}
$b = new bar;
$b->barbar(); // prints: "foofoo"
?>
```

Source: `http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php`

Comment: This isn't really explaining much to why his is not working given he assigns an additional value in the child class which is where his problem occurs.

Comment: Ohh yes it did, you did access the parent class variable in your attempt. $this refers to parent class. However it got overrided by the child class variable. Please refer to the link i have posted, to have better understanding. Specially those comments below.

Comment: I understand it perfectly well i did not ask the question. Your answer does not explain why his variable assignment was not set to the correct value. Because you did not explain that `$this` will belong to the parent class. Thus he was overwriting a variable. Your answer is just a snippet of code with no context to explain the output behavior he was getting.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a thing as parent attributes. Attributes are part of the instance of the class, i.e. the object. In that sense, you're object has one single attribute "type" (which you defined twice). The interpreter is assigning to it the value specified on the most specific class you're object is an instance of (speaking of inheritance), that is Dog.
So as printProperties method (both implementations, in parent and in child class) prints the value of the object "type" attribute, them both will output de same value (except for the `<br>`).